Check checkbox status in tree-view Tkinter
The code below executes flawlessly when the checkbox in the treeview, obtained from the given link, is utilised. However, I am currently in need of a way to extract the data from the selected/checked checkbox rows using a for loop. Initially, I would verify the status of the checkbox and if it is checked, I would add it to an array list that is used for the data-frame. It would be greatly appreciated if you could assist me by providing guidance and the necessary code to retrieve the selected row data from the Tree-view.
Is there a way to make an multicolumn treeview at tkinter with multiples checkboxes?
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()


class CbTreeview(ttk.Treeview):
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kw):
        kw.setdefault('style', 'cb.Treeview')
        kw.setdefault('show', 'headings')  # hide column #0
        ttk.Treeview.__init__(self, master, **kw)
        # create checheckbox images
        self._im_checked = tk.PhotoImage('checked',
                                         data=b'GIF89a\x0e\x00\x0e\x00\xf0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00!\xf9\x04\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00,\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0e\x00\x0e\x00\x00\x02#\x04\x82\xa9v\xc8\xef\xdc\x83k\x9ap\xe5\xc4\x99S\x96l^\x83qZ\xd7\x8d$\xa8\xae\x99\x15Zl#\xd3\xa9"\x15\x00;',
                                         master=self)
        self._im_unchecked = tk.PhotoImage('unchecked',
                                           data=b'GIF89a\x0e\x00\x0e\x00\xf0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00!\xf9\x04\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00,\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0e\x00\x0e\x00\x00\x02\x1e\x04\x82\xa9v\xc1\xdf"|i\xc2j\x19\xce\x06q\xed|\xd2\xe7\x89%yZ^J\x85\x8d\xb2\x00\x05\x00;',
                                           master=self)
        style = ttk.Style(self)
        style.configure("cb.Treeview.Heading", font=(None, 13))
        # put image on the right
        style.layout('cb.Treeview.Row',
                     [('Treeitem.row', {'sticky': 'nswe'}),
                      ('Treeitem.image', {'side': 'right', 'sticky': 'e'})])

        # use tags to set the checkbox state
        self.tag_configure('checked', image='checked')
        self.tag_configure('unchecked', image='unchecked')

    def tag_add(self, item, tags):
        new_tags = tuple(self.item(item, 'tags')) + tuple(tags)
        self.item(item, tags=new_tags)

    def tag_remove(self, item, tag):
        tags = list(self.item(item, 'tags'))
        tags.remove(tag)
        self.item(item, tags=tags)

    def insert(self, parent, index, iid=None, **kw):
        item = ttk.Treeview.insert(self, parent, index, iid, **kw)
        self.tag_add(item, (item, 'unchecked'))
        self.tag_bind(item, '<ButtonRelease-1>',
                      lambda event: self._on_click(event, item))

    def _on_click(self, event, item):
        """Handle click on items."""
        if self.identify_row(event.y) == item:
            if self.identify_column(event.x) == '#5': # click in 'UnServed' column
                # toggle checkbox image
                if self.tag_has('checked', item):
                    self.tag_remove(item, 'checked')
                    self.tag_add(item, ('unchecked',))
                else:
                    self.tag_remove(item, 'unchecked')
                    self.tag_add(item, ('checked',))



tree = CbTreeview(root, columns=("Table No.", "Order", "Time", "Served", "Unserved"),
                  height=400, selectmode="extended")

tree.heading('Table No.', text="Table No.", anchor='w')
tree.heading('Order', text="Order", anchor='w')
tree.heading('Time', text="Time", anchor='w')
tree.heading('Served', text="Served", anchor='w')
tree.heading('Unserved', text="Unserved", anchor='w')
tree.column('#1', stretch='no', minwidth=0, width=100)
tree.column('#2', stretch='no', minwidth=0, width=600)
tree.column('#3', stretch='no', minwidth=0, width=100)
tree.column('#4', stretch='no', minwidth=0, width=70)
tree.column('#5', stretch='no', minwidth=0, width=30)

tree.pack(fill='both')

for i in range(5):
    tree.insert('', 'end', values=(i, i, i))
root.mainloop()



waiting for your valuable reply
I am currently in need of a way to extract the data from the selected/checked checkbox rows

You can go through all the rows which have tag "checked" and get the values for those rows:
result_list = [tree.item(row, "values") for row in tree.tag_has("checked")]


If you want only values from a column, for example "Order", use:
result = [tree.set(row, "Order") for row in tree.tag_has("checked")]


Sir this code give me all field but we need only column 2
result_list = [tree.item(row, "values") for row in tree.tag_has("checked")]
result ('2', '2', '2')  but we need only '2' only one column
please give me code the give me only one column
regard

Don't put comment as answer.  You can edit your question to provide the extra requirement.  Which column do you want actually?

for two columns
result = [tree.set(row, "Order","qty") for row in tree.tag_has("checked")]

It doesn't return values of two columns, but set column "Order" to value "qty" for all rows.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

sorry sir / Which code should I use to retrieve only two columns?
